# Image not loading when using Vue @click function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a website using Vue.js 3 Composition API an Single File Components.

In the header there is an image I want to trigger a function when the user clicks it, but when adding `@click="myFunction"` the image does not render anymore in the webpage.

```js
<script setup>
import App from '../App.vue';
import router from '../router/index.js'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
    console.log('mounted!')
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
})



const handleLogo = () => {
    console.log("clicked on logo!")
    }


</script>

<template>
        <header class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 text-center" >
            
            <div class="img-aerobot">
                <a href="/"><img src="/src/assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="" width="10%" class="aerologo"></a>
            </div>
            
        </header>
  

...
</template>
```

I already tried adding `@click='handleLogo'` to the anchor tag, image and div separately and the output is the same, as soon as that is present, the image is not being rendered.

Comment: First things first. Why are you importing App.vue and router in this page?

Comment: I would remove the anchor tag altogether. I believe clicking the anchor tag would cause the page to refresh. Once you remove the anchor tag you can add the click event to either the image or div tags

Comment: @LLai thanks! I removed the anchor tag and added the event to the div. The element still does not show, but I open the inspect element menu from browser, it shows on responsive view. Weird

Comment: @FedericoPerezDiduch odd, perhaps that issue is due to a mediaquery or some css